# Why does duplicity require the GnuPG passphrase when rotating backups?

Tags: linux, backup, encryption, public-key-encryption, duplicity

I am using [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) 0.7.05 to periodically backup a directory that resides on a Linux system, using a GnuPG key pair with an encrypted private key. Since the public key is not encrypted, the passphrase is not required for the backup process, but it is required for accessing the backups.

I would now like to automatically delete old backups using the `remove-all-but-n-full` and `remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full` [duplicity options](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html). To my surprise, duplicity will ask for the GnuPG passphrase when removing old backups, which makes it impossible to do so automatically.

Why does duplicity ask for the GnuPG passphrase in this case? It seems to me that it should not need to access the backup contents just to figure out *which* backup file sets to remove.

Comment: If you have disk space you could keep a local un-encrypted duplicity backup (option --no-encryption), maintain an psuedo-rsync'd encrypted copy of that, and then rsync that encrypted copy to your offline destination.

Answer (score 2):

this was just topic on the mailing list

http://duplicity-talk.nongnu.narkive.com/fGHD22Kq/remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full-num-and-decryption

..ede/duply.net

Comment: That is indeed the explanation, although I am not fully convinced that it cannot be done otherwise. I don't suppose that there is some sort of workaround that does not involve deleting file manually?